# How to show some part of text in different color i.e data between @ and } should be in different color

Tags: javascript, reactjs

want to show data between `@` and `}` in different color

example:@{data} @{message} should be different color in "one @{data} and @{message}
@{somedata} should be in different color in "two @{somedata}

```
const data1 = [
      {name: 'one @{data} and @{message}'},
      {name: 'two @{somedata}'},
      {name: 'three @{data}'},
      {name: 'four @{data}'}
];

export default React.createClass({
  render() {
      return (
          <div>
          {data1.map(function(a) {
              return (
                  <p>{a.name}</p>
                )
            })}
          </div>
        )
  }
})
```

Comment: are you expecting a solution like this https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-d1f2x4 ?

Comment: @Jayavel Thanks for your efforts to solve my problem but @ comes any number of times in a sentence whenever @ comes I want to show that data in red color and also have to remove {} also

Answer (score -1):

I used `replace`

[full code sample : https://codepen.io/yunyong/pen/qveLZL](https://codepen.io/yunyong/pen/qveLZL)

```js
  <p dangerouslySetInnerHTML={ 
                    {__html:  a.name
                    .replace(/@{/gi, '<span style="color:red">')
                    .replace(/}/gi,'</span>')} 
                  }>
                    </p>
```

Comment: @Sandhya My pleasure :)